# Is there a way to disable logs forwarding to GCP when using cloud.google.com/go/logging in development/test environment?

Tags: go, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I though about "hiding" logger initialization and returning a normal logger (`log`) from it when running the code in development environment and a `cloud.google.com/go/logging` one when deployed on GCP.

But `cloud.google.com/go/logging` logger does not have the same interface as `log`, so it would need some extra wrapping and I hope I can avoid that.

Looking at the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/logging), I can't find a standard way to do this. If there is no way to do it, what's the common approach to avoid spamming google cloud logging with logs not coming from preproduction/production environment? Aside from making the logs noisy, logs ingestion have a cost I would like to avoid in some situations.

Comment: The best idea I have would be to mock it and use the mock in dev. I think that you can look at the way they do their [tests](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/logging/v1.4.2/logging/logging_test.go) internally

Comment: As an idea - you can configure logs exclusion based on some indicator of evironment: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions

Comment: @OleksandrBushkovskyi I think that would still be billed: _Therefore, excluding logs doesn't reduce the number of `entries.write` API calls._

Comment: @NuLo I believe this notification is about quotas on `entriews.write` API calls. The documentation also says: "letting you exclude matching log entries from being routed to the sink's destination or from being **ingested** by Cloud Logging". In my expirience logs exclusion affects ingestion log volume charges.

Comment: @OleksandrBushkovskyi you're probably right, billing is always complicated on these products. I think you should write this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @Sergiusz answer, you can log your development into the same log or logs with the templated name and use [logadmin](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/logging/logadmin) package to delete the log(s) by the name. You can do it at the end of execution, in scheduled process or from a command line. You can do it also using `gcloud logging logs delete` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/logs/delete). If you have multiple logs you will need to call "delete" multiple times per log.

However, I would recommend to mock the package instead because, using it may  exhaust your API quota on the development project. So, if writing logs to STDOUT is sufficient, the fastest approach would be just to mock the Logger type.

P.S. I would recommend to open an issue in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go with your use case and ask for the change. It might lead to the breaking change though, but it is still important to provide the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

To recap the comments:
Google Cloud allows creating [exclusion filters for Sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions).
According to [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/gain-visibility-and-take-control-of-stackdriver-costs-with-new-metrics-and-tools#:%7E:text=logging%3A%20the%20exclusion%20filter%20):

> you can choose to export your logs to BigQuery, Cloud Storage or Cloud Pub/Sub **without needing to pay to ingest them** into Stackdriver. You can even use exclusion filters to collect a percentage of logs, such as 1% of successful HTTP responses.

Additionally, note that the first 50 GiB of logs per project per month are free [1](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing).
First 30 days of storage in the Log buckets are also free.

Answer (score 0):

In the end as suggested by @leo-y, I kind of mocked a logger and hide implementation details behind an interface. I was reluctant to do this because I'm new to golang, but in the end that's not so much code:

logging/Logger.go:

```
package logging

// Logger is just an interface to abstract away what
// kind of logger we return on initialization
type Logger interface {
    LogInfo(string)
    LogWarning(string)
    LogError(string)
    Close()
}
```

logging/initialization/logging.go

```
package initialization

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    customLogging "organization/module-name/logging"

    "cloud.google.com/go/logging"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

// GetLogger return a logging client
func GetLogger(onCloud bool) customLogging.Logger {
    if onCloud {
        return getLoggerGCP()
    }
    return loggerConsole{}
}

func getLoggerGCP() loggerGCP {
    ctx := context.Background()
    projectID := "PROJECT-ID"
    client, err := logging.NewClient(ctx, projectID, option.WithCredentialsFile("/path/to/credentials.json"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create logging client: %v", err)
    }
    return loggerGCP{
        client: client,
        logger: client.Logger("logs-name"),
    }
}

type loggerGCP struct {
    client *logging.Client
    logger *logging.Logger
}

type loggerConsole struct {
}

func (logger loggerGCP) LogInfo(s string) {
    stdlogger := logger.logger.StandardLogger(logging.Info)
    stdlogger.Println(s)
}

func (logger loggerGCP) LogWarning(s string) {
    stdlogger := logger.logger.StandardLogger(logging.Warning)
    stdlogger.Println(s)
}

func (logger loggerGCP) LogError(s string) {
    stdlogger := logger.logger.StandardLogger(logging.Error)
    stdlogger.Println(s)
}

func (logger loggerGCP) Close() {
    logger.client.Close()
}

func (logger loggerConsole) LogInfo(s string) {
    log.Printf("INFO: %s\n", s)
}

func (logger loggerConsole) LogWarning(s string) {
    log.Printf("WARNING: %s\n", s)
}

func (logger loggerConsole) LogError(s string) {
    log.Printf("ERROR: %s\n", s)
}

func (logger loggerConsole) Close() {
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "organization/module-name/logging/initialization"
)

func main() {
    logger := initialization.GetLogger(false)
    defer logger.Close()
    logger.LogInfo("hello")
}
```

I didn't challenge that code much yet, so maybe it will have some quirks